# I have the problem with my ASP.Net C# shared project, i can not find Controllers and Models folders?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-10

I have the same problem, how can I recover it and continue with development to add another logic?
i searched answers on the web, i found that once deployed the Controllers and Models folders are converted in dll files stored in the bin folder.
I want to know how can i restore it like folders

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you mixing two things:

1. code of your program - it's all the text files with **.cs** extensions, you should also have **.csproj** and probably **.sln**. Download Visual Studio Community edition and open either the sln file (or just the csproj if there is no sln) - then you will see the code. F5 to run
2. DLL files - they are a result of compiling your code. If you have just the dll files, you cannot really edit the code and modify the program - you are looking at the end result of the whole process.

You can always decompile the DLL - something similar to the original code from the DLLs, but at your level don't do it.

Try to search for some tutorials on .net project structure (like [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/aspnet-core-application-project-structure)) to learn which directory means what.

To get even better understanding, try running and compiling your program from command line using `dotnet run` - you will face some issues at first with directories etc, but work through them, it will be very beneficial.

Once you do that, you can go back to actually writing the code. And remember, ChatGPT knows a lot about this, and is able to help you get through the problems way faster than SO